# equation that takes datetime into account

Tags: python, dictionary, model, range, gurobi

I am trying to set up a function with two different dictionaries.

```
               datetime          demand
0      2016-01-01 00:00:00       50.038
1      2016-01-01 00:00:10       50.021
2      2016-01-01 00:00:20       50.013

      datetime               dap
2016-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    23.86
2016-01-01 01:00:00+01:00    22.39
2016-01-01 02:00:00+01:00    20.59
```

As you can see, the dates are equal however the deltaT is different. 
The function I have set up is as follows

```
for key, value in dap.items():
    a = demand * value
    print(a)
```

How do I make sure that in this function the dap value `23.86` is used for the datetime interval `2016-01-01 00:00:00 until 2016-01-01 01:00:00`? This would mean that from the first dictionary indexed values 1-6 should be applied in the equation for `2016-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    23.86`, and indexed values 7-12 are used for dap value 22.39 and so on?

```
     datetime                   demand
0      2019-01-01 00:00:00       50.038
1      2019-01-01 00:00:10       50.021
2      2019-01-01 00:00:20       50.013
3      2019-01-01 00:00:30       50.004
4      2019-01-01 00:00:40       50.004
5      2019-01-01 00:00:50       50.009
6      2019-01-01 00:01:00       50.012
7      2019-01-01 00:01:10       49.998
8      2019-01-01 00:01:20       49.983
9      2019-01-01 00:01:30       49.979
10     2019-01-01 00:01:40       49.983
11     2019-01-01 00:01:50       49.983
12     2019-01-01 00:02:00       49.983
```

Comment: Those data examples are dictionaries?  Are the items in the first *dictionary* all ten minutes apart and the items in the second *dictionary* all 60 minutes apart? So that there are always six *dictionary1* items for each *dictionary2* item?

Comment: I have added a bigger data excerpt which shows that in the first dict all are ten min apart. All items in the second dictionary are 60 min apart as well. So yes, alway 6 dict1 for 1 dict2 item!

Comment: Would you have a suggestion or a approach for this @wwii ? @

Comment: You can write two for loop. Outer loop for dict 60 min, inner loop for dict 10 min (Second loop 6 times for each first loop).

Comment: Is your data type a dictionary? The examples you have given do not look like string representations of dictionaries.

Comment: This can help realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/

Comment: Both are pandas data series, however I thought as these contain a key and a value that they are considered to be a dictionary. Does that change anything?